# Conditional Weighted Average using SUMPRODUCT, SUMIF, ISNUMBER

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to write a formula that will return the weighted average WAM based on weighted average of the Balance for all Products that satisfy both of the following conditions:

1. Product = "Direct Finance Lease"
2. BU_Type contains the word "truck" in it

I believe a conditional SUMPRODUCT is neccassary and ISNUMBER may need to be used to satisfy the 2nd criteria.  As seen in the image below, the correct output should be:

28.065  =  ((26*1674611)+(30*1787893))/(1674611+1787893)

I apologize, my current formula is not anywhere near functional at this point:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B:$B=ISNUMBER("truck"),--$A:$A="Direct Finance Lease",$C:$C,$F:$F)/SUMPRODUCT(--($B:$B=ISNUMBER("truck"),--$A:$A="Direct Finance Lease",$C:$C)
```

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: It might be easier if you added a helper column, balance x WAM and you could use SUMIFS and COUNTIFS. I'll post an answer if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply SJR. I would greatly appreciate it if you could post an answer

Comment: `ISNUMBER("truck")` will never work because "truck" is not a number! You need something like ISNUMBER(SEARCH("truck",...)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this set up, which is slightly simplified from yours but essentially the same, I added the last column (E is just C x D) and used this formula

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E6,A2:A6,"B",B2:B6,"*truck*")/SUMIFS(C2:C6,A2:A6,"B",B2:B6,"*truck*")
```

[image]

If you don't want a helper column, could use this

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="B")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("truck",B2:B6))*(C2:C6)*(D2:D6)))/SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="B")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("truck",B2:B6))*(C2:C6)))
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help!  I ended up adding an extra column to make it simpler